# VIRTUAL_ENV is not detected in pydev

Tags: python-2.7, pydev, virtualenv

I'm using pydev with Eclipse and virtualenv with python2.7 on Debian Squeeze
My python script requires the variable `os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']` but there is no `VIRTUAL_ENV` key when I debug.
However if I type in the terminal:

```
. /my_virtualenv/bin/activate
python
import os
os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
```

then I can see `VIRTUAL_ENV` is in the variable `os.environ`
Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that virtualenv sets the `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable as part of it's activate script.  Pydev doesn't run that activate script, so it doesn't have knowledge of that environment variable.

You can set it in the run configuration though.

1. Click the little down arrow next to the run icon.
2. Click "Run Configurations..."
3. In the left pane select the run configuration you want to modify.
4. Select the "Environment" tab on the right side.
5. Click "New" and put `VIRTUAL_ENV` as the name and the value that you desire.